# Well built rails code for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get into rails by examining well built code
where can i find typical open source rails project that i can download
and learn from ?
i'm interested in facebook connect integration (facebooker), tag clouds, searching in
my website

I'm not looking not tutorials or screen casts

Thanks!

Comment: This is also addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193632/whats-a-good-rails-example-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248371/whats-the-best-open-source-ruby-on-rails-project-to-learn-from) gives a good list
- [a list of projects](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/04/best-ruby-open-source-test-suites-awards/) with good test-suites
- a [list of open source rails apps](http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2010/05/31/five-rails-apps-to-study-and-learn-from.html) to learn from

Answer (score 1):

Have a browse of [ruby tool box](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories.html) and download some open source. For example there's [refinery](http://refinerycms.com/) and [zena](http://zenadmin.org/en), two content management systems and [Rboard](http://github.com/radar/rboard), a forum. Depends what you want really but there's plenty out there. Ruby toolbox entries are ordered by github watchers and forks to give you an idea of their popularity.

Comment: Thanks, this can be useful but i'm also looking for a complete open web app that i can investigate

Answer (score 1):

I really like looking at the commits in [teambox](http://github.com/teambox/teambox).
I find it a bit more complicated. But there's also [spree](http://github.com/railsdog/spree).

There's also [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which is really interesting to look at too.

Finally, I'd recommend you to follow the [rails](http://github.com/rails/rails) commits (it's the only commits feed I have in my Google Reader).

Answer (score 0):

Gady, this is an extremely rich topic you're asking about and resources are all over the internet. Try starting at http://rubyonrails.org/.

You should be able to find tens of questions just like yours (asked and answered) by searching SO at the top bar.

Comment: I'm looking for well designed code that i can download and watch working. not tutorials or screen casts

Comment: Strange that you mark this question down given how many others also recommend Railscasts and/or tutorials.

Comment: downvotes (and I don't really see what differentiated your answer to the extent of a -1) can come from anyone with enough rep to click the down-pointing triangle. Not saying the -1 didn't come from the Q's author, just that it ain't necessarily so... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has an excellent series of videos.

http://railscasts.com/

An extremely valuable resource.

Radiant is a CMS that you can download for free and see how it works.  It is a great piece of code to look at and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, part of it is the building process, so one feasible approach is to read a tutorial like http://railstutorial.org/book

then when in Chapter 2, you will use Scaffold, and at that time, you will have some basic code to look into how a basic Rails app is.

I also suggest you use source control like Git, Mercurial, or SVN to commit different phases of the project, from creating the rails project and then after each step, so you can diff what the changes are during each step.

If you already have Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.1, and sqlite3, then you can

```
rails new myproj
cd myproj
rails generate scaffold foo name:string salary:integer gpa:float note:text
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

and now you can use http://localhost:3000/foos to create, display, update, delete the foo records, and have quite a bit of source code to look at.  Most of the customizable code is in `app`, with `css` and `javascript` in the `public` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that most open source Rails projects are shared on Github, so it may be interesting to browse its Ruby section and look for most watched or most forked projects:

http://github.com/languages/Ruby

Steady stream of new interesting projects to take a look at :)

Answer (score -1):

And don't forget the official:

guides.rubyonrails.org

well there is one "bigger" project on github, waiting for downloading and contribution...
but it's a little controversial because of the security issued they have (had?)

It's still worth a look:

http://github.com/diaspora/diaspora